# Show that 2-manifold embedded in R^4 is homeomorphic to Klein bottle

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following parameterized 2-surface in $\mathbb{R}^4$:

$$F(x,y) = ((r\cos y + a)\cos x, (r \cos y + a)\sin x, r \sin y \cos \frac{x}{2}, r \sin y \sin\frac{x}{2})$$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ are parameters, and $r,a$ are large positive constants. How would one show that this surface is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle? Is there an explicit homeomorphism?

Comment: What's your definition of the Klein bottle? In this case I would look at the rectangle $0\leq x\leq2\pi, 0\leq y\leq 2\pi$ of the parametrization space $\mathbb{R}^2$ and show that opposite sides of this rectangle are coincident as curves in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the appropriate orientations.

Comment: ah, so the boundary of the rectangle completely determines the fact that it's a Klein bottle? you don't have to look at the interior of the rectangle?

Comment: The definition I'm familiar with of a Klein bottle topologically is as a rectangle with sides appropriately identified (similar to the definition of a torus as a rectangle with sides appropriately identified). The other thing you want to show is that your parametrization is an embedding (and not, e.g., just an immersion).

Comment: There's also a purely computational approach - compute the Gaussian curvature by Brioschi's formula, then integrate and apply Gauss-Bonnet to get the Euler characteristics. But that's a monstrous computation, probably.